# Validation Rule on new record

Tags: apex, validation

I have validation rule on account as below:

```
AND( 
(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) > DATE(2019,08,01)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Type)
))
```

This is working fine when I edit the record, But I want this validation rule on new account creation. Any suggestions?

I tried to use `ISNEW()` but didn't get any success.

Comment: This looks like http://xyproblem.info/ ,, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal  I want to create validation rule on account that TYPE(Picklist field on account) field should not be null and createdDate > 08/01/2019 while creating a new account.

Comment: Try having two parts to the rule, one like you have here but with ISNEW as false and one with ISNEW true and replacing check of CreatedDate with "now/today" - on the assumption the created date will be set to now on creation.

Comment: I am not sure why this wouldn't work for new records as it is....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel surprised as well when I see your validation rule not working for new records. But I tested it out and you are right. It is not working for new records. I think the reason is because createdDate field is not populated during the time the validation rule is running.

So I updated your validation rule a little bit to work for new records:

```
And(
    ISBLANK(TEXT( Test_Picklist__c )),
Or(
    ISNEW(),
    DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) > DATE(2019,08,01)
)
)
```

Tested working in my developer org.

Comment: This is working fine, Thank you for the help.